# Generating keys in Public key Cryptography

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, keytool

Our application depends upon several other teams, like the SSO team for instance. So in order for our application to use SSO's (login) service, we do the following:

In the following example keystore and deststore passwords are "Passcode"

```
keytool -genkey -alias App_env1 -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore_App_env1.jks -keysize 2048 -validity 365

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore_App_env1.jks -destkeystore app_env1.p12 -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12

keytool -export -alias App_env1 -keypass Passcode -keystore keystore_App_env1.jks -storepass Passcode -rfc -file MyApp_env1.pem
```

After the first line is run, I get a JSK file.

After second line is executed, I get a P12 file

After third file is executed, I get a PEM file.

Our application build holds the P12 file and we hand over the PEM file to the SSO team.

My questions are :

1. Why is the JSK file generated?
2. Why does our application hold the P12 file and hand over the PEM file to SSO team?
3. In which file does the public key reside?
4. In which file does the private key reside?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the questions in order:

1. that's a good question, only the PKCS#12 file should be generated;
2. because the PEM file is ASCII armoured and contains the certificate containing the public key while the P12 file holds the private key as well;
3. see 2;
4. see 2.